# Как транслировать звук в конкретный наушник?

Tags: java, аудио, desktop

Пишу десктопное приложение на Java. 
Одна из задач - сделать так, чтоб заранее записанный аудиофайл выводился на один конкретный наушник (правый или левый). 
Нигде не могу найти ничего об этом. 
Самое близкое, что нашла: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458780/sending-a-buzz-sound-to-ear-bud-left-or-right
Но там речь идет об Андроиде и, кажется, не работает.

Comment: Как вариант, можно генерировать аудиофайл в стереоформате, в одном канале нули а в другом канале нужная Вам информация. И потом стандартным проигрывателем гнать этот файл в звуковой канал.

Comment: Спасибо! А где можно почитать, как это делать?

Comment: @MariaLifshits скачайте какое-нибудь легкое приложение для работы с аудио-файлами, и потому уже в гугл вбейте "название_программы развести в разные уши / по каналам". там работы 2 мин: найти нужные крутилки (которые по дэфолту будут стоят на серединах) и подкрутить как вам надо. сохранить.

Comment: [А где можно почитать, как это делать?] Почитайте форматы аудиофайлов. Поищите библиотеки Явовские для работы с аудио файлами. Как-то так. Ну, или разбираться с интерфейсом к аудио драйверу. Операционка-то какая? Винда или линукс?

Comment: Операционка - macOS. 
Поняла, буду думать.